# TeamCity to change template parameter without changing it in children

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, continuous-delivery

I have a lot of deployment configurations that are adopting root template.

And now I want to change one Parameter (environment variable) in the root template, but to pin the old value in all children deployment configuration.

The goal is to force all new deployment configuration that would be created to have a new value inside their deployment. And then step-by-step move with old deployment configuration and change this value only where it is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1:
Create a new template with new value and use it for all new configuration. Let old configuration continues with old root template. Then incrementally you can migrate your old configuration to new template.

Option 2:
If you don't have more configuration from root template, You can change the value in the root template. The movement you change the new value That will be reflected in all children configuration. Then go to each children configuration and manually change the value(old value). I know it is a very tedious job if you have more configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying the template, you can change the parameter of your template, to set a variable value. 
Your parameter will have inside the template the value of `%EnvVarSomething%`

Define the value at `<Root>` level with you old value for the parameter `EnvVarSomething`.

Then, you can easily migrate your configuration by overriding the parameter `EnvVarSomething` in each Build Configuration or Project.

Comment: Thanks, but that actually is the same as overriding this param in each of children templates. It would take lots of time, but looks like there is no other choice.

Comment: In fact, it is a bit more faster, since you can define the parameter at project level, instead of build configuration level.

Answer (score -1):

Go into the root edit project settings and find the configuration template in question. at the very right of the row containing your template there should be a drop down. Inside the dropdown should be an option called copy template. Make a copy of the template with a different name and make changes to that instead. Then you will have a new template to use that doesn't have children to worry about.